# Limit number of clients that can connect to the server at the same time- Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

Good evening. First thing sorry for my noob English. I need to do for my shool project server with connection limited at the same time. For every succesfull connection I need to make Thread and add it to some collection, lets say ArrayList and then the number of active threads were increasing. When thread finished his job the number of active threads was decreasing and the thread is removed from collection. When we get new request and the number of maxClients was equaled to max number, then we send to client an error message. I'm not allowed to use Timer, TimerTask and other performed classes for this task. Every help, tips and tricks are welcome.

This is the code for potential connection limits but it doesnt work CORRECTLY.

```
public class Server {
       static int activeUsers = 0; 
      public static void main(String[] args){
          Server server = new Server();
          server.ServerWork();

      }
      public void ServerWork(){
      ArrayList<ClientThread> list;
      ServerSocket serverSocket;
      Socket socket;
       ClientThread client;
          list= new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
             serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9001, 50);//// backlog must be higher than activeUsers
      while (true) {
           socket = serverSocket.accept();
            activeUsers ++;
            if (client < 5){ ////5-value for maxUsers
                Thread thread = new ClientThread(socket);
                list.add((ClientThread) dretva);

                if (list.size() > 0) {

                    Iterator<ClientThread> iterator = list.iterator();
                    for (iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                        ClientThread d = iterator.next();
                        d.start();
                        if (!d.isAlive() || d.isInterrupted() || d.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
                            activeUsers--;
                            iterator.remove();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
    ///if the list was full send user error message
  else {
                try {
                    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    outputStream.write("ERROR 01;".getBytes());
                    outputStream.flush();
                    socket.shutdownOutput();
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                   ////some text here
                }
            }


      }
 }}

///class for client requests
class ClientThread extends Thread{
private Socket socket;
public ClientSocket(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}
@Override
public void run() {


    try {
        InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (true) {
            int i = inputStream.read();
            if (i == -1) {
                break;
            }
            sb.append((char) i);
        }
        osw.write("Hi from server");
        osw.flush();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        socket.shutdownInput();
        socket.close();

    } catch (SocketException exception) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

    }

}

@Override
public synchronized void start() {
    super.start(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see an actual question here for the first part, and you shouldn't ask two questions in one post. Off topic but you don't need to flush or shutdown before close, and neither `clientThread` not `socket` should be instance members of the server class: they should be local variables. There is no apparent reason why the backlog needs to be greater than the number of active clients. In the client handler you can't read until end of stream and then write back to that socket.

Comment: And the 'multithread' part of 'multithread clients' is irrelevant. All you care about at the server is connections.

Comment: Backlog must be higher than maxNumber because client from other application can send request for increased maxNumberofThreads and then that number is added to current value of maxUsers. clientThread represents class for connected client. Thats code for implementation the limited current users on the server but it doesn't work. Sorry for 2 question, that' s my first post and I'm sorry for that. Next time i will be more careful . I promise :)........Every connected client must be a new Thread if there was a space. If there is no space client get's message ERROR01;.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Any backlog value will accomplish that. Backlog doesn't include current connections. And you now need to define 'doesn't work'.

Comment: Student project. I didnt write task.

Comment: When i send 10 reqursts at the same time  there is no more than 1 element in the collection and i cant get message for full server. I want to implement that i can store user connection into collection l thread and increase the number of active users.  The number of users are actualy the number of active threads and the active threads are stored into collection. I dont know how can i caught thread end and decrease the number of active threads?

Comment: Well you need to make the list of threads a member of the server class, not a local variable, and remove the current thread from it and decrement the count when you close the accepted socket.

Comment: Tnx man. It works